# Express : unable to load the intended path with middlewares

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, middleware

i am beginer with Express and I have a rather strange functionality that I am achieving with the middlewares. Here I call a URL which is fetched by its middleware and then on `next()` another middleware gets called. now in the `next()` of the second middleware I need to  load the component, but issue is that, URL is not changing after the first middleware's `next()`.

Code :

Express App : Router :

```
app.use('/common/global/login', mainHandler);
app.use('/common/*', subhandler, SuccessComponent);
```

Middleware :

```
export function mainHandler(req, res, next) {
    const global-url= "someURL"
    if (global-url) {
        return fetch(global-url)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((response) => {
                if (response.data) {
                    next();
                } else {
                    throw Error(response.statusText);
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                res.redirect('/session-expired');
                next(error);
            });
    }
    res.redirect('/session-expired');
}

export function subhandler (req, res, next) {
    const other_url= "someOtherURL"

        return fetch(other_url)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((response) => {
                if (response.data) {
// here it not loading the SUCCESSCOMPONENT as the URL still remains /common/global/login
                    return next();
                }
                throw Error(response.statusText);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                next(error);
                res.redirect('/session-expired');
            });
    }
    res.redirect('/session-expired');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error with your code, it may be worth fixing this first to see if it is contributing to the error you are having:

```
export function mainHandler(req, res, next) {
    const global-url= "someURL"
    if (global-url) {
        return fetch(global-url)
        ...
```

You cannot define a variable that contains a hyphen `-`, as this read as the subtract operator.

`const global-url = ...` , should be `const global_url = ...`

And of course update all instances where you are calling this variable.

---

In your code's current state, `next()` is not being called by the first middleware because `if (global-url) {...}` would not return a thruthy value therefore not triggering the next middleware in the chain.

Try:

```
export function mainHandler(req, res, next) {
    const global_url= "someURL"
    if (global_url) {
        return fetch(global_url)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((response) => {
                if (response.data) {
                    next();
                } else {
                    throw Error(response.statusText);
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                res.redirect('/session-expired');
                next(error);
            });
    }
    res.redirect('/session-expired');
    // Note that if this 'if' is not satisfied, 'next()' is not called.
}
```